# injecting Svelte-generated nodes into static DOM

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I have a static HTML file and want to augment it with dynamic Svelte components:

```html
<ul id="list">
    <li>first</li>
    <!-- dynamic list items should be added in between static ones -->
    <li>last</li>
</ul>
```

(This is a simplified example; the "first" and "last" elements are more complex, re-generating them in Svelte is not an option.)

```
import List from "./List.svelte";

new List({
    target: document.querySelector("#list"),
    props: {
        items: ["foo", "bar"]
    }
});
```

```
<script>
let items;
</script>

{#each items as item}
<li>{item}</li>
{/each}
```

This appends dynamic items to the end of the list though. Is there an idiomatic, declarative way to insert them in the middle instead?

The only solution I can think of is cumbersome, non-declarative DOM manipulation:

```
<script>
import { onMount } from "svelte";

let items;

onMount(() => {
    let container = ref.parentNode;
    container.removeChild(ref);
    // manually change order
    let last = container.querySelectorAll("li")[1];
    container.appendChild(last);
})
</script>

<span bind:this={ref} hidden />

{#each items as item}
<li>{item}</li>
{/each}
```

(I'm not even sure this is valid because `span` elements are not allowed as direct `ul` descendants, plus manually discarding `ref` might confuse Svelte?)

Comment: I don't know why you do this But back to your question. In the same way as you pass the middle to your component you can pass the first and last items to the component.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Passing those pre-existing DOM nodes to the component doesn't work: `items: ["foo", ...document.querySelectorAll("#list li"), "bar"]` results in `[object HTMLLIElement]` being rendered - which is disappointing.

(I do this because I believe in progressive enhancement, using Svelte to augment an existing architecture rather than subjugating it with Svelte seizing control of the entire page.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `anchor` option to mount a component adjacent to a specific node:

```js
import List from "./List.svelte";

const target = document.querySelector("#list");
const anchor = target.lastChild; // node to insert component before

new List({
    target,
    anchor,
    props: {
        items: ["foo", "bar"]
    }
});
```

Demo: https://svelte.dev/repl/1a70ce8abf2341ee8ea8178e5b684022?version=3.12.1

The full API is documented here: https://svelte.dev/docs#Client-side_component_API

Comment: Oh, thanks (also for Svelte in general) - not sure how I'd missed that.